# Pod to Pod connection with using multiple port

Tags: rabbitmq, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Google Cloud Container Engine cluster with 2 Pods, `master` and `slave`. Each of them runs RabbitMQ instance, that supposed to be joined into one cluster.

Ports exposed from Dockers aren't available from other machine, but could be accessed only through a Service. That's not a problem, I could establish a service for each instance (one-to-one, service-to-pod), and point each Pod to opposite service IP.

The problem that RabbitMQ uses more that one port for communications. That means that service IP should open all this ports from underlying Pod. But I cannot specify list of shared port for a Service, and if I create a new service for each port each of them will have own IP.

Is there any way to expose list of ports from same Docker/Pod on same internal IP address using Container Engine cluster? maybe some special routing configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587387/how-to-expose-dynamic-ports-using-kubernetes-service-on-google-container-engine), and unfortunately has the same response: Kubernetes / Google Container Engine does not currently have a way to expose a range of ports for a service at the current time. There is an [open issue in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/1802) to address this use case.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you for the link, will wait for fix